# How to read first word of a binary file in VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read the first word of a binary file which tells me how many steps that the file contains.  I'm a complete newb when it comes to working with binary data in VB.net

What's the best to do this ?  I literally just need to read the value of the first word of the file - I don't need to do any more with it than that.

I found this code but it just returns an empty string:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim readStream As FileStream
        Dim msg As String
        Try
            readStream = New FileStream("C:\FreeStyler\Chases\Quadzilla - RedGreenBlue - Shrinking Squares (Pattern 23) - Static.chb", FileMode.Open)
            Dim readBinary As New BinaryReader(readStream)
            msg = readBinary.ReadString()
            MsgBox(msg)
            readStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: The word "word" can mean several things.

Comment: I don't have experience with the binary reader so I can't help there, but once you get it to a string, you can do `yourString.split(" ")(0)` to find the first word

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
readStream = New FileStream("C:\FreeStyler\Chases\Quadzilla - RedGreenBlue - Shrinking Squares (Pattern 23) - Static.chb", FileMode.Open)
Dim readBinary As New BinaryReader(readStream)
msg  as Integer = readBinary.ReadInt32()
MsgBox(msg.ToString)
readStream.Close()
```